Constant error while referencing function in package (TypeError: 'module' object is not callable)
I get error while trying to execute pytest UTs for the project.
E       TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I have the following repository structure:
├───src
│   └───company
│       ├───acc
│       └───dp
│           └───logic
│               ├───business
│               │   ├───__init__.py 
│               │   ├───alter_customer.py
│               │   ├───filter_customer.py
│               │   └───review_customers.py
│               └───general
│                   ├───some_function.py
│                   └───__init__.py
├───tests
│   └───company
│       └───dp
│           └───logic
│                └───business
│                    ├───test_alter_customer.py
│                    └───test_review_customers.py
├───conftest.py
└───pyproject.toml

Each file under business package contains one function with the same name as the file.
Let's imagine file filter_customer.py like that:
def filter_customer(i: int) -> int:
    return i

Let's imagine file review_customers.py like that:
from company.dp.logic.general import some_function
def review_customers() -> str:
    x = some_function("custom")
    return x

Let's imagine file alter_customer.py like that:
from company.dp.logic.business import filter_customer
def alter_customer() -> str:
    x = filter_customer(10) <- this line raise error while trying to run Unit Test
    return x


UT looks something like that:
from company.dp.logic.business import alter_customer
def test_alter_customer():
    x = alter_customer()
    assert x == 10


./business/__init__.py file for business package looks like that:
from company.dp.logic.business.alter_customer import alter_customer
from company.dp.logic.business.filter_customer import filter_customer
from company.dp.logic.business.review_customers import review_customers


./general/__init__.py file for business package looks like that:
from src.company.dp.logic.general.some_function import some_function 

pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]

[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = [
]
testpaths = ["tests/company/dp/logic/business"]
python_files = "test_*.py"
python_functions = "test_*"
pythonpath = "src"
norecursedirs = "*"

How to correctly organize the packages/modules in such scenario?
The goal was to have one function per file and packages like business and general to cover imports from modules.
I have tried multiple versions.
When I use direct import from module/file, it work. It also works when I call function from different package like general.
# This works:
from src.company.dp.logic.business.filter_customer import filter_customer

# With this I have error, even though IDE resolve it correctly:
from src.company.dp.logic.business import filter_customer


# This works:
from src.company.dp.logic.general import some_function

def review_customers()
    c = filter_customer(10)
    return something

I prepared repository which allows to recreate this problem: https://github.com/paweltajs/module-package/tree/main
Edit. Few other observations.
When I change the name of the function to differ from file name, I got different error:
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'f_filter_customer' from partially initialized module 'company.dp.logic.business' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Repositories\module-package\src\company\dp\logic\business\__init__.py)

When I put import within the function, it works. Like that:
def alter_customer() -> str:
    from company.dp.logic.business import filter_customer
    x = filter_customer(10)
    return x


src shouldn't be considered to define a package, just a directory that contains the top-level module/package company.

@chepner I added link to GitHub with example.

filter_customer is a module that also contains a function named filter_customer. You're calling filter_customer, not filter_customer.filter_customer.
(There is no reason to define a separate module for each function; don't do that.)

There are reasons to have separate files for each function. Why this is then working when calling general ?

I don't see how general has anything to do with this. Is your last code block supposed to be three different files? The first import makes sense; the second one does not, because it only imports the module into the current namespace, not any functions in that module.

Importing functions from general works in business module. So I can do ‘ from src.company.dp.logic.general import some_function’ an it correctly imports the function, not module. Problem is only when I do this between modules under business.

Yes, because general.some_function actually is a function. business.filter_customer is not; it's a module that contains a function, which is why business.filter_customer.filter_customer works.

some_function is under the same rule, there is some_function.py file and it is in init file. The only difference is that it it under different folder/package.

Updated structure, code, added general init file.

I'm afraid I don't believe that. There's some other difference you are overlooking.

(Your question shows you importing some_function, but you don't call it; you still call filter_customer, and it's unclear if that's the function imported by the first import or the module imported by the second.)
